# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED using Laravel 9 with Laravel Sail on PHP 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, laravel-sail

I am building an app with Laravel, Vue 3 and Inertia.js.

I tried to set up a development server with Laravel Sail.

I have docker running in my machine and all the containers are running, the problem is that whenever I access `localhost` it throws me these errors even though after I run the script `sail npm run hot`:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:8080/css/app.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:8080/css/all.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:8080/js/manifest.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:8080/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My docker-compose.yml file contains the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
       image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
       volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
       networks:
           - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

I am on a Windows 11 machine using WSL2 and Ubuntu-20.04

Comment: Could you explain why you think there will be HTTP request coming back from both port `3000` and `8080`? If you didn't specify APP_PORT in your .env the default serving port will be `80`.

Comment: And indeed, Dockerfile only has `${APP_PORT:-80}:80` in it, so that's the only port that's going to be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it: Remove the file named "Hot" ,, Location Public/Hot. This file was created on Cpanel file manager but does not exist in my local system.

After couple of days I found that ,before running npm run build just terminate php artisan serve command this solves my issue , Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue as well.

Was doing the bootcamp tutorial and made the website available on LAN but the css/js didn't wanna load (connection refused), obvious because it tries to access the css/js in the non public map(resources)

The hot folder is created by the vite server for hot-reloading so shutting that down also removes that map.

I also did run the command npm run build that puts all the css/js files into the public folder. I assume that was also needed otherwise they are not available to the public.